# Getting Twitter friends to allow user to tag them in post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter

Im using the following Twitter API calls to get the list of people a user follows:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids

The idea is to allow the user to send DMs to their friends. Now I have a performance issue ahead of me and I want to see how others have solved it. I have 2 options:

1) Whenever the user logs on, if they have a Twitter account I query the friend list, index alphabetically in an array for easier access and store it in the user's sessions. The problem with his is that it's done every time the user logs on, so if he's following a lot of people it's gonna take a long time, since it can only lookup 100 users at a time, and there's also the rate limit deal. The advantage is it will always have the user list up to date.

2) Do the same when the user associates his Twitter account with my site, and store it in the database, this will make it easier when I have to search the friend list since I can just execute a SELECT query using LIKE and get a matching list to whatever the user is typing, I'm just not sure if this is wise because it would take up a lot of space.

I'm using PHP with CakePHP framework and JQuery. Any other ideas are welcome.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to go with the DB approach, it takes very lone to query for all the friends so I'd rather do it as little as possible. Now, how would you approach updating this list?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of retrieving the users you could also retrieve the id's only and search the extra information of the users when needed.

Here's an example in jQuery

```
$.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=smashingmag&callback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.ids, function(idx, item) {
        console.log('userId: ' + item);
    });
});
```

For more information on the method see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids

Comment: I retrieve the IDs so I can get the usernames, and that's the thing, what I need is the screen name and there is no way to parametrize the call to the API, the only information y have to search is the name.